# Is there a way to see the level 40 dialogue again?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

When your hero reaches level 40, you could be treated to a special dialogue session, is there a way to view this again?

Comment: You seem to have asked the same question 3 times in rapid succession. Having connection issues?

Comment: That would probably explain why Stack asked if I was a bot.. fixing that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of version 1.6.0, you can now view the level 40 5☆ unit dialogue again! By going to Settings, you you can select the Hero Catalog to view your collected units and see their dialogue for being summoned as well as their level 40 5☆ dialogue.

[image: settings]

The heroes with glowing backgrounds are the ones that have their level 40 5☆ dialogue available to view.

[image: hero catalog]

[image: unit dialogue options]

---

A compendium of all of these "level 40 dialogues" can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/AKvidVFB) (the character names are the Japanese names, though, so Aqua = Azura, etc.).